The Benefit of Command Pattern over direct Action Binding
There is something that I couldn't understand regarding the command pattern.
What is the advantage of using the Command pattern compared to directly assigning actions to buttons?
Let me demonstrate it with the following example.
// receiver
class Document {
    public void save() {}
    public void open() {}

}
interface Command{
    void execute();
}
// Concrete Commands
class SaveCommand implements Command {
    private Document document;

    public SaveCommand(Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }
    @Override
    public void execute() {
        document.save();
    }
}
class OpenCommand implements Command {
    private Document document;

    public OpenCommand(Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        document.open();
    }
}
// Invoker: Generic Button
class Button {
    private Command command;

    public void setCommand(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void execute() {
       command.execute();
    }
}
// Client Code
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Receiver: Document
        Document document = new Document();

        // Commands
        Command saveCommand = new SaveCommand(document);
        Command openCommand = new OpenCommand(document);

        // Buttons (Invokers)
        Button saveButton = new Button(saveCommand);
        Button openButton = new Button(openCommand );

        saveButton.execute();  
        openButton.execute();
    }
}

What is the edge that this command pattern gives us over this approach?
class Document {
    public void save() {}
    public void open() {}

}

interface Button {
    public void execute();
}
class SaveButton implements Button{
    private Document document;

    public SaveButton (Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        document.save();
    }
}

class OpenButton implements Button{
    private Document document;

    public OpenButton (Document document) {
        this.document = document;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        document.open();
    }
}


// Client Code
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Receiver: Document
        Document document = new Document();

        // Buttons (Invokers)
        Button saveButton = new SaveButton(document);
        Button openButton = new OpenButton(document);

        saveButton.execute();  
        openButton.execute();
    }
}

In both cases, the buttons are separated from the logic. My question is: What is the benefit of the extra Command layer in the first example? How does using the Command pattern improve this situation over directly binding the actions to buttons as shown in the second example?
What is the benefit of it in code rather than just in theory?

Two that I can think of: (1) the Command can be tested and verified without the Button, and (2) it's only one line of code to change the Command if necessary.   If you never have to change the action associated with the Button, maybe you don't need a Command.
